Why does nni run multiple python files resulting in crashing of my PC?
I have tried the following:
experimentName: hyper-param searching
authorName: Raj
trialConcurrency: 1
trainingServicePlatform: local
searchSpacePath: searching_space.json
multiThread: true
useAnnotation: false
tuner:
    builtinTunerName: Random

trial:
    command: python train.py
    codeDir: .
    gpuNum: 1

localConfig:
    useActiveGpu: true
    maxTrialNumPerGpu: 2
    gpuIndices: 0

The above results in so many multiple python files running in background and crashes my laptop. Also, when I try with useActiveGpu: false, the problem still persists. And even if I somehow prevent my laptop from crashing, the link doesn't open.
But when I use for CPU with code as:
authorName: default
experimentName: hyperparam searching
trialConcurrency: 1
trainingServicePlatform: local
useAnnotation: false
searchSpacePath: searching_space.json
tuner:
  builtinTunerName: Random
  classArgs:
    optimize_mode: minmize
trial:
  command: python train.py
  codeDir: .
  gpuNum: 0

The nni link works and all the tasks are Running to Succeeded as it should.
I am using virtual environment from Pycharm IDE, and nni is of version 3.0 and I have Windows 10 as my OS. And I have all my variables set .to(device) where my device is cuda. The code runs fine when not run under nni, but the problem only occurs when using GPU in nni.
I tried experimenting with trialConcurrency, useActiveGpu, maxTrialNumPerGpu, gpuIndices. But all results in same thing. Either the laptop crashes or the link doesn't open and even if it does it will have nothing in Running, Failed or Succeeded and the server doesn't work immediately after.
